# CakePHP Testsuite and Ant

Tags: cakephp, ant

Is it possible to integrate Ant and the CakePHP Test suite?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that should be possible by calling the testsuite shell script (`cake testsuite app all`, for an overview of the available options have a look at the script's help output) from your Ant script.

Comment: Do you know how to fail an ANT build if a test case failed?

Comment: I don't use Ant myself, but did you set the failonerror attribute?

Answer (score 1):

With the new stuff simply calling `cake testsuite app all`
isn't going to work especially if you want to do it from the command line. The internets will show you a billion examples of creating grouped suites but nothing that just runs it all like the web interface does but wait I forget the common practice in php land is to do a ton of extra work for no good reason. You know like typing in each test file set for your test suites line by line.

Coming from a java background I like how you can one button push run all tests so I did something small to simplify everything.

This solution means you can't make test suites anymore and expect them to work with tests aggregated elsewhere. You have to never make suites. Or just name them differently and hide them. But hey that's ok because the trade off is worth it.

MAKE SURE YOU NAME YOUR FILE correctly --> AllTestsTest.php

In my Cases folder I created a test suite file that uses the recursive directory lookup.

```
<?php
/**
 * AllTests class
 *
 * This test group will run all tests.
 *
 * @package       Cake.Test.Case
 */
class AllTestsTest extends CakeTestSuite {

/**
 * Suite define the tests for this suite
 *
 * @return PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite the instance of PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite
 */
        public static function suite() {
                $suite = new CakeTestSuite('All Tests');

                $path = dirname(APP_TEST_CASES);

                $suite->addTestDirectoryRecursive($path);

                return $suite;
        }
}
```

The next step involves changing cake code in lib/​Cake/​Console/​Command/​TestShell.php .

```
@@ -52,9 +52,10 @@
         public function addTestDirectoryRecursive($directory = '.') {
                 $Folder = new Folder($directory);
                 $files = $Folder->tree(null, true, 'files');
-
+                
                 foreach ($files as $file) {
-                        if (substr($file, -4) === '.php') {
+                        
+                        if (substr($file, -8) === 'Test.php' && substr($file, -13) != 'TestsTest.php') {
                                 $this->addTestFile($file);
                         }
                 }
```

This is a hack but it solves two problems so well that I just can't stop grinning.

Instead of capturing any file with .php extension it actually adheres to the convention the web interface is using. This will allow you to one click run AllTests in the web interface and the behavior of the web test runner will be the same as your cli tests when they run.

Standardization of how tests are aggregated is truly an afterthought for the code contributing cake community of wonderful people.

Now, I know you are thinking.."Why not just extend CakeTestSuite and override the method?" Good luck with that. Your mileage may vary. Cake isn't truly Object Oriented like Java or other compiled languages and the Cake way of going about extending classes inside it's guts means adhering to conventions that are barely, if ever at all, documented clearly.

Making this change forces a convention across all possible testing platforms using the pattern *blahblah***Test.php** for the test runner/loader and since there is no way to merge separate test suites together without explicit lines of code because the genius's decided that any .php file was a test even if it really is a test suite.

Why didn't the phpUnit community come up with a way to aggregate test suites without the need for writing anything? This is basic functionality for most languages, convention over configuration right? Directory/package structure dictates the composition so why not take advantage of something so obvious? The Cake devs have had so many chances to make that possible but I guess they enjoy typing in each test case in each suite line by line as if it were a fun thing to do. Typey tappy typey typey

For example here the Cake core AllTests.php file they use for their all in one.

```
class AllTests extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite {

/**
 * Suite define the tests for this suite
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public static function suite() {
        $suite = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite('All Tests');

        $path = CORE_TEST_CASES . DS;

        $suite->addTestFile($path . 'BasicsTest.php');
        $suite->addTestFile($path . 'AllConsoleTest.php');
        $suite->addTestFile($path . 'AllBehaviorsTest.php');
        $suite->addTestFile($path . 'AllCacheTest.php');
        $suite->addTestFile($path . 'AllComponentsTest.php');
        $suite->addTestFile($path . 'AllConfigureTest.php');
        $suite->addTestFile($path . 'AllCoreTest.php');
        $suite->addTestFile($path . 'AllControllerTest.php');
        $suite->addTestFile($path . 'AllDatabaseTest.php');
        $suite->addTestFile($path . 'AllErrorTest.php');
        $suite->addTestFile($path . 'AllEventTest.php');
        $suite->addTestFile($path . 'AllHelpersTest.php');
        $suite->addTestFile($path . 'AllLogTest.php');
        $suite->addTestFile($path . 'Model' . DS . 'ModelTest.php');
        $suite->addTestFile($path . 'AllRoutingTest.php');
        $suite->addTestFile($path . 'AllNetworkTest.php');
        $suite->addTestFile($path . 'AllTestSuiteTest.php');
        $suite->addTestFile($path . 'AllUtilityTest.php');
        $suite->addTestFile($path . 'AllViewTest.php');
        $suite->addTestFile($path . 'AllI18nTest.php');
        return $suite;
    }
}
```

Smelly smelly smelly...

They have a nice start with the recursive directory reader but agreeing on an intuitive convention that could free up some valuable time for the rest of the planet is completely out of the question I suppose. PHP programmers...meh

Making the change above is harmless enough and it will make it simple to run your tests without having to line by line call each suite of test that you had to write line by line. Like the Cake people who wrote their tests.

If you are running a jenkins build this solution is so rad because you only need to run a single ant task instead of multiple explicit suites. If you already took the time to line by line create test suites you could try hacking the same file like I did but it wouldn't match up with the browser test runner.

This basically forces your shell to adhere to a convention of Test.php instead of something that follows a convention of breaking when I want to do something simple like RUN ALL TESTS. It's as if the guys that wrote the tests for CakePHP decided they would never actually write tests for cakephp applications that use the framework, use it with a continuous integration platform, a browser based test runner, and a standalone cli in windows or nix. It is a conspiracy for sure.

to run your tests just do this

$ cake test app AllTests    <-- purty isn't it. It's intuitive and it works and you didn't have go through the hassle of adding each test into a suite. Now your ant target can be simple as pie.

```
<target name="phpunit" description="Run All The Cake Tests Like A Boss" depends="ensure-tmp-folders">
  <exec executable="bash" failonerror="true" dir="${basedir}/src/app/Console">
   <arg value="cake"/>
   <arg value="-app"/>
   <arg value="${basedir}/src/app"/>
   <arg value="test" />
   <arg value="app"/>
   <arg value="AllTests" />
   <arg value="--coverage-clover"/>
   <arg path="${basedir}/build/logs/clover.xml"/>
   <arg value="--log-junit"/>
   <arg path="${basedir}/build/logs/junit.xml"/>
  </exec>
 </target>
```

When you check in your code and the build server notifies you that your tests failed instead of never knowing it because you forgot to go through the process of adding it to a suite you can fix it before your boss fires you.